# stancl\tenancy: in Api Resources, the tenant() helper is not correctly detecting the tenancy context

Tags: php, laravel, multi-tenant

I'm using [Api Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-resources) provided by laravel, alongside with [stancl\tenancy package](https://github.com/archtechx/tenancy) ([multi-database approach](https://tenancyforlaravel.com/docs/v3/multi-database-tenancy)).

in one of my controllers, i have the following code:

```
    return $someTenant->run(
        function () {
            return (new someApiCollection(someApi::all()));
        }
    );
```

the current landed tenant has an ID of 1, and $someTenant is a tenant with an ID of 2.

inside the someApiResource class when i log the tenant()->id, it shows the id of 1.

```
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {

        \Log::info([
            'toArray tenant()' => tenant()?->id,
        ]);
        ...
    }
```

considering that I've run $someTenant->run(..) on an upper level, it's not detecting the correct tenancy context.

### what can be done?

---

UPDATE:
when i put the same log on the constructor of the API resource, I get the correct tenant ID, but on the toArray method, I still get the incorrect ID of the tenant.

---

UPDATE: replacing the $someTenant->run(. . .) with tenancy()->initilize($someTenant) worked for me.
now, the code in my controller instead of this:

```
return $someTenant->run( function () {
     return (new someApiCollection(someApi::all()));
});
```

looks like this:

```
tenancy()->initialize($someTenant);
return (new someApiCollection(someApi::all()));
```

I haven't touched anything else, and it works. But I'm not sure about the reasoning behind it. Any Ideas?